# Looking Up Value to Return Hourly Rate

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table storing hourly pay rates and a start and end value associated to each.  The theory being that your hourly pay is dependent on your takings sitting between the start and end values.

Table Example - dbo.PayScales

```
PayScaleId   Starting   Ending   HourlyRate
1            0.00       32.88    12.00
2            32.89      34.20    12.50
3            34.21      35.52    13.00
```

I have the takings stored in a separate table along with a person id, and I need to lookup the hourlyrate based on the takings (which I am having a complete mind block about)

Table Example - dbo.Employees

```
EmpId     Takings    HourlyRate
1         33.50
2         31.19
3         37.00
```

So my exepected results would be:

```
EmpId 1 Hourly rate = 12.50
EmpId 2 Hourly rate = 12.00
EmpId 3 Hourly rate = 13.00 as the value is greater than the ending value.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` together with `TOP`:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Employees e
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 p.HourlyRate
    FROM dbo.PayScales p
    WHERE 
        e.Takings BETWEEN p.Starting AND p.Ending
        OR e.Takings > p.Ending
    ORDER BY p.Ending DESC
) t
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/489823)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Of course @FelixPamittan's answer solves the problem, but with a small change in your data it's down to a simple join.

Change the highest `Ending` to a really high value (999999999), greater than any  `Takings`, or NULL:

```
FROM #Employees AS e
JOIN #PayScales AS p
ON e.Takings BETWEEN p.Starting AND p.Ending
-- or
ON e.Takings BETWEEN p.Starting AND COALESCE(p.Ending, 999999999)
```